# CSS tabs not showing up in anything other than latest version of Chrome

Tags: css

I'm trying to figure out exactly why these tabs aren't showing up in anything other than the latest version of Chrome (21) that I'm using.

I thought it may have to do with the `after` tag, but that should be working on most major browsers (IE8+) according to: [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-type: none;
}

li {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 46px;
    padding: 14px 10px 0 14px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;      
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}

li.dark_green {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/49NPN.png) repeat-x;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
}

li.dark_green:after {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/ggxKy.png) repeat-x;
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 66px;
    position: relative;
    height: 46px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 400;
    left:50px;
    bottom:32px;
}

li.light_green {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/CRuk8.png) repeat-x;
    position: relative;
}

li.light_green::after {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/K7DAL.png) no-repeat;
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 66px;
    position: relative;
    height: 46px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 400;
    left:50px;
    bottom:32px;
}

.text {
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 500;
}
.light_green_text {
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 500;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="light_green"><span class="text">Symptoms</span></li>
    <li class="dark_green active"><span class="light_green_text">Problems</span></li>
    <li class="light_green"><span class="light_green_text">Behavior</span></li>
</ul>​
​
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/someprimetime/6F4MC/7/

Comment: Seems to me like http://i.imgur.com/ blocks the requests with a referrer from jsfiddle.net with a 403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://imgur.com/ blocks the access to your four images, when they are loaded with a [referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) of http://fiddle.jshell.net. You can see the `403 Forbidden` response in the network tab of your developer tools. After loading the images directly (opening their urls in a separate tab), the cached versions will be used an can be seen in your fiddle demo.

[image: example of not loaded image]

Not sure why it works in your Chrome, it might be set not to send the referrer along. Have a look at your preferences.

Update: I've filed [a report](http://imgur.userecho.com/topic/120841-403-forbidden-on-jsfiddlenet/) on this topic.

Comment: Weird. I don't know why I didn't think to check that.. I never would have guessed that's why. Thanks!